# ContainerRequestFilter is called twice

Tags: jax-rs, cxf, cdi, openwebbeans

I have simple Apache Meecrowave 1.2.1 (OWB+CXF) application with ContainerRequestFilter:

```
@Singleton
@Provider
public class AppInstanceAndSecurityFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    ...
    @Inject
    private AppInstanceService appInstanceService;
    ...
    @Context
    private ResourceInfo resourceInfo;
    ...
}
```

AppInstanceAndSecurityFilter class is returned in getClasses() method of Application subclass.

The problem is that filter is called twice and there are two instances of filter - one with all successfully resolved @Inject and @Context references and one with all @Inject references null and all @Context references successfully resolved.

Why there are two instances of filter, one with null @Inject references?

Comment: The one with null @Inject reference is managed by the jaxrs runtime provider, while the one is managed by CDI. I think this is because you have used `@Singleton` which is from `javax.inject.Singleton`

Comment: @maress I removed Singleton annotation, but it didn't change anything. Still two instances, one with null Inject references. Strange.

I defined filter in getSingletons() instead of getClasses() and resolved filter instance manually and it works as it should (only one instance will fully resolved Inject and Context references), but I don't see reason why getClasses() shouldn't work.

Comment: It is because the getClasses() instances are instantiated by CXF and not CDI. The best is likely to configure the scanning to exclude the providers/endpoints your don't want and not implement getClasses. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-7789

Comment: @RomainManni-Bucau Thanks for reporting this. But if getClasses() instances are only instantiated by CXF and there are two instances of ContainerRequestFilter, something must be instantiating that other instance - maybe CXF CDI integration? And ApplicationScoped resource classes defined in getClasses() work without problems (they are called only once and all references are resolved successfully). But maybe that's a happy accident :-)

Comment: How do you bootstrap your app